# Ember.js - Whats the proper way to handle property translations?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, translation

I have a model with a `gender` property, which can be "female" or "male".

What's the best way to handle the translation of that property?

I thought of some ways to tackle this, but not sure if I'm overthinkering this or solving it poorly.

1) **Make a helper** or tagless component that receives the value, has the translations service injected and translates it. With an aditional flag to capitalize or lower case the output.

2) Just **use `t` helper and `concat`** for the translation key, eg: `{{t (concat "gender." model.gender)}}`. This is very straight forward and I will be copy-pasting this everywhere, looks messy.

3) **Computed property in the model**. I feel like injecting the translations service in my models is wrong (just my impression, if this is the proper way I'm good with it)

4) **Computed property in the component** that has to show the gender. This is like option 2 but in the component instead of the template, will be copy-pasting this a lot.

Comment: the second option is what i usually do

Comment: I personally do #1.

Comment: I usually do 2. 1 looks good too but for such simple task helper feels like a little bit too much

Comment: mix #1 & #2 : Something like a `t-words` helper which can be a translator for common words such as 'male', 'female', 'next', 'cancel' ... which can be used as is out of any context. which is just a wrapper of `{{t (concat 'words.' param)}}` and you call `{{t-word model.gender}}`